# Countdown Timer not Stopping with clearInterval()

Tags: javascript, clearinterval

I'm having a problem get this countdown timer to stop at zero so the time won't show as a negative value. The console.log is getting called and works fine but for some reason the `clearInterval()` is not. This is driving me crazy and I'm close to quitting.

```js
const timerContainer = document.getElementById('timerContainer');   

const THREEMINUTES = 60 * 0.1;//5 seconds for testing
 
startTimer(THREEMINUTES, timerContainer);

function startTimer(duration, display) {

  let start = Date.now();
  let diff, min, sec;

  let timer = () => {
   diff = duration - (((Date.now() - start) /        1000) | 0);
   //use bitwise to truncate the float
   min = (diff / 60) | 0;
   sec = (diff % 60) | 0;

   min = min < 10 ? '0' + min : min;
   sec = sec < 10 ? '0' + sec : sec;

   display.textContent = min + ':' + sec;

   if (diff <= 0) {
    stopTimer();
    submit.disabled = 'true'; 
   };

  };

  //call timer immediately otherwise we wait a      full second
  timer();
  setInterval(timer, 1000);

  function stopTimer() {
   clearInterval(timer);
     console.log("time's up", diff);
    };
}
```

```html
<div id="timerContainer"></div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are not saving the result of `setInterval(timer, 1000);`

you should use this:

```
let timerId;
timer();
timerId = setInterval(timer, 1000);

function stopTimer() {
    clearInterval(timerId);
    console.log("time's up", diff)
};
```

As you might see, the result of `setInterval` is a number (object in node), and all you then need to do is pass that value to `clearInterval` thus we save the value in the variable `timerId` for reference.

Answer (score 2):

Don't pass the function that you want stopped to [`clearInterval()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/clearInterval).

Pass a reference to the timer that you started, **so you need to make sure that when you start a timer, you capture a reference to the ID that will be returned from it**.

```
// Function that the timer will invoke
function callback(){
    . . .
}

// Set up and initiate a timer and capture a reference to its unique ID
var timerID  = setInterval(callback, 1000);

// When needed, cancel the timer by passing the reference to it
clearInterval(timerID);
```

Answer (score 0):

The code is fixed make sure you fix your submit button code.
You should first assign the value of setInterval to a variable. That variable is used while calling clearInterval which infact clears the interval.

```
const timerContainer = document.getElementById('timerContainer');   

const THREEMINUTES = 60 * 0.1;//5 seconds for testing

startTimer(THREEMINUTES, timerContainer);
var timer = null;
function startTimer(duration, display) {

        let start = Date.now();
        let diff, min, sec;

        let timer = () => {
            diff = duration - (((Date.now() - start) /        1000) | 0);
            //use bitwise to truncate the float
            min = (diff / 60) | 0;
            sec = (diff % 60) | 0;

            min = min < 10 ? '0' + min : min;
            sec = sec < 10 ? '0' + sec : sec;

            display.textContent = min + ':' + sec;

            if (diff <= 0) {
                stopTimer();
                submit.disabled = 'true'; 
            };

        };

        //call timer immediately otherwise we wait a      full second
        timer();
        timer = setInterval(timer, 1000);

        function stopTimer() {
            clearInterval(timer);
        console.log("time's up", diff);
    };
}
```

Comment: Answers shouldn't just be working code. They should explain what the problem was and how you solved it.

Comment: You are resetting the value of `timer`